# Is it possible to have RelativeLayouts in a RadioGroup

Tags: android, radio-button, android-relativelayout

I want a row in my layout with

radioButton, edit text, textview

surrounded by a radioGroup. However
 the radioGroup does't seem to work this way.
I'm generating this layout with code not xml, just to show how it would look like:

```
<ScrollView>
    <LinearLayout>
        <RadioGroup>
         <RelativeLayout>
            <RadioButton>
            <EditText>
            <TextView>
         </RelativeLayout>

         <RelativeLayout>
            <RadioButton>
            <EditText>
            <TextView>
         </RelativeLayout>

        </RadioGroup>
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

I can select all radiobuttons, the group is not working.
what is wrong, or how would I solve this problem?

Comment: A RadioGroup is thought to group RadioButtons and nothing else. You break the grouping if you add extraneous bodies in it. Probably, you'll have to make a custom control which extends a RadioButton to make it include an EditText and a TextView.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can't have RelativeLayouts in a RadioGroup. The view will actually be rendered as expected, but the radio buttons won't function (they will lose their grouping). If you need an EditText inside each button, you'll have to code the radio button functionality yourself. However, if you just need different text styles inside the radio button, look at SpannableString.